# What is the fastest way of reaching Albanian tourist attractions?

Tags: air-travel, airports, albania, ecotourism

When I went to Albania on a day trip, I was told that it was the tourist destination of the future (but there again they would say that)

It's certainly developing fast, and would attract tourists with it's scorching hot temperatures, it's beaches to lay on and Burtrint National Park to feast your eyes upon.

[image: Burtrint National Park - Albania]
The problem is, the only airport is nowhere near the tourist destinations (5 hours I believe)

My question is - **What is the quickest way to get to Albania from the UK, are flights (or whatever form of travel) frequent, and is there progress on building a new airport near tourist destinations such as Saranda?**

When I went for a day trip, I went from Corfu by boat on an organised tour. Corfu is only about 7 miles from Albania at the nearest points. But going from port to port, you're looking at around 1 and a half hours.

Comment: Scorching hot temperatures ? That only attracts British tourists :)

Comment: You could say that. :) If I knew it was going to be 43C, I may have not gone to the National Park where you have to walk miles.... @blackbird57

Comment: I wouldn't call any of the Adriatic beaches particularly attractive...

Comment: Some are better than others agreed @JonathanReez but how attractive they are doesn't really matter to most tourists as long as there is a pool, beach and bar.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on where exactly you want to go. If you're going for [Shkodra](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Shkodra), the fastest route would be to fly to Montenegro and take a cab:

[image]

If you want to go to [Vlore](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vlor%C3%AB), where some of the best beaches are, you could instead fly to Tirana and take a bus:

[image]

Considering how fast things tend to get built in Southern Europe, I wouldn't hope to fly into a new airport any time soon. Use [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/) to optimize your route between flying into Montenegro, Albania or Greece.